# Model in a modal window in angularjs is empty

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hello I am using [angularjs ui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and I have one text field in a modal window, which when I try to print it in alert window it is empty. Any reasons why? Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xf5YzJCAvnwjLHHWvxhk?p=preview) of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the

- `$scope.testField`

into

- `$scope.myModel.testField` *(or `user.firstName`...)*

As mentioned in this video [angular JS - best practice](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY) (29:19):

> "Whenever you have ng-model there's gotta be a dot in there somewhere. If you don't have a dot, you're doing it wrong."

See updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/z1ABPEUB7Nxm1Kxey9iv?p=preview

NOTE: with a nice reminder of the video-minute from article [Nested Scopes in Angular JS](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html)

Comment: Great if that helped. I suggest watch this video, it is very interesting, really. Enjoy Angular ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an updated plunker for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/tvE4DoovZ6NheYj1HMho?p=preview

When using the modal service with ui-bootstrap, you need to encapsulate your model in a container scope, eg:

`$scope.form = { testValue: '' };`

Also read this for more information about nested scopes: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html