# Angular js directive two way databinding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, directive

So I want to create a directive that embeds the angular ui-select directive, with my configuration.
However when I pass my variable to ng-model it is not updated in the parent. Only in the ui-select itself. I was assuming that calling '=' in an isolated scope would lead to two way data-binding. Do I have to call $apply somewhere?
Any help?

so my html usage should look like this:

```
<interpreter-search ng-model="booking.interpreterId" id="field_interpreter"/>
```

directive:

```
angular.module('omserviceApp')
.directive('interpreterSearch', ['InterpreterSearch' , function (InterpreterSearch) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
          interpreterId: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.refreshInterpreters = function (query) {
                InterpreterSearch.query({query: query}, function (result) {
                    scope.interpreters = result;
                }, function (response) {
                    if (response.status === 404) {
                        scope.interpreters = [];
                    }
                });
            };

        },
        templateUrl: 'scripts/components/entities/interpreter/interpreter-search.html'
    }
}]);
```

template:

```
<ui-select ng-model="interpreterId">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Find an interpreter...">
    <span ng-bind="interpreterId"></span>
</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="interpreter.id as interpreter in (interpreters | filter:  $select.search)"
                   refresh="refreshInterpreters($select.search)"
                   refresh-delay="0">
    <span ng-bind="interpreter | interpreterHtml"></span>
</ui-select-choices>
```

Comment: “Whenever you have ng-model there’s gotta be a dot in there somewhere. If you don’t have a dot, you’re doing it wrong.”. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882681/model-in-a-modal-window-in-angularjs-is-empty

Comment: I have a  dot in my html usage:
<interpreter-search ng-model="booking.interpreterId" id="field_interpreter"/>
or where should the dot be placed?

Comment: I noticed this: <ui-select ng-model="interpreterId">. If you would create a plunkr I will be more than happy to have a look at why it isn't working.

Comment: use of `ng-model` doesn't seems valid. isn't it should be done with forms.

Comment: the directive is pplaced in a form like this:
<form>
<form-group>
<label>interpreter</label>
<interpreter-search ng-model="booking.interpreterId" id="field_interpreter"/>
</form-group>
</form>